# Connect to sample SOAP 1.1 with PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Hello i need to connect to SOAP web services with password, username and SourceId in **php**.
the SOAP request is:

```
POST /webservices/AgentOnlineReservation.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 54.228.189.53
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetHotelsData"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetHotelsData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <SourceId>string</SourceId>
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </GetHotelsData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the native [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) library:

```
$client = new SoapClient('linkhere.com/AgentOnlineReservation.asmx?wsdl');

$response = $client->GetHotelsData(array(
    'SourceId' => '...',
    'UserName' => '...',
    'Password' => '...'
));

print_r($response);
```

The link passed in the SoapClient call is the WSDL (Web Service Description Language) file.

Comment: Hello MrCode and Thanks for the quick answer
but i get this now: 
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://54.228.189.53/webservices/AgentOnlineReservation.asmx?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://54.228.189.53/webservices/AgentOnlineReservation.asmx?wsdl"

Comment: Check your server can make outgoing network connections. Also try with http (not https) to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: MrCode Thanks i changed the https whit http and now it works great.
Thank you very very much.

Comment: I recommend reading this tutorial that i've found http://www.lampjunkie.com/2010/03/get-phps-soapclient-to-speak-with-javas-jax-ws/   hope it helps