# How to use SoapClient with Soap 1.2

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I've read the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043067/connect-to-sample-soap-1-1-with-php).
Question is how do I control the version of soap in this way?
What is the soap version that launched there?

**EDIT**: How do I do the same as in the accepted result but with Soap 1.2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to sample SOAP 1.1 with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043067/connect-to-sample-soap-1-1-with-php)

Comment: Then ask a real question... and do not force people to get to see the other question just because you are too lazy to express it.

Comment: @perror: This should be pretty the same I guess , therefore I gave the link

Comment: Have you checked SoapClient's documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php? It is well explained there.